# Rails. Ошибка при выполнении rake test: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, юнит-тесты, test-driven-development

Есть модель:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.timestamps null: false
    end        
  end
end
```

И тест к ней:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "shoudl always pass" do
    assert true
  end

end
```

При выполнении команды `rake test` появляется следующая ошибка:

```
  1) Error:
UserTest#test_shoudl_always_pass:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "name" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (980190962, null, null, null, null, 2015-10-12 13:38:26, 2015-10-12 13:38:26).
: INSERT INTO "keywords" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2015-10-12 13:38:26', '2015-10-12 13:38:26', 980190962)
```

Пробовал комментировать fixtures или заполнять их, все равно не помогает.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема описана в ответе постгресса - у вас поле 'name' пустое при сохранении модели, с кодом помочь не могу

Comment: В таком случае, почему постгрес пытается вставить что-то в базу когда его об этом никто не просит?

Comment: Выполняется запрос INSERT INTO "keywords" ... нужно искать по коду где и для чего он выполняется

Comment: Пытается не постгрес, пытается тестовый фреймворк. Скорее всего, это fixtures от модели `Keyword`, вы просто не смогли их выкорчевать/исправить. Постарайтесь получить полный стектрейс ошибки (если не получается в `stdout`, смотрите в `log/test.log`).

Comment: Можно ли каким либо образом убрать проверку и использование fixtures при проведении теста?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась. Закоментировал строку fixtures :all в test_helper.rb